# How do I append multiple dicts into one dict of a list?

Tags: python

I have the following python code

```
data = []
data2 = [1,2,3]

for x in data2:
    row = {
        'data': []
        }
    row['data'].append({'record': x})
    data.append(row)

print(data)
```

I would like to receive an output like this:

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "Record": 1
            },
            {
                "Record": 2
            },
            {
                "Record": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

it doesn't work with the append() method, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

`row` must stay outside the for loop, otherwise it repeats for number of times.

```
data = []
data2 = [1,2,3]

# Moved out of the loop
row = {
    'data': []
    }
for x in data2:
    row['data'].append({'record': x})

# Moved out of the loop
data.append(row)
```

And to get formatted output:

```
import json

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: This also works for the single case: `data = [{'data':[{'record':n} for n in (1,2,3)]}]
`

Comment: Optimal! Thanks for the shortest solution

Comment: Just to note, `data.append(row)` doesn't need to be after the loop. I'd probably move it before, but that's just personal preference. Depends what the real code does.